# mvc remember me out of the box in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Been having troubles implementing the RememberMe function in MVC 4.

I created a new MVC4 Internet Application from Visual Studio 2012.  This includes already the RememberMe `checkbox` on the log in page.  I am assuming that it also includes all the code necessary for that `checkbox` to work.  But it doesn't.  I haven't added a single line of code to this MVC4 app yet.

I'm using `WebSecurity.Login` with the persistCookie: `model.RememberMe` and my web.config says:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

and yet after so many minutes, the session expires and the user must log in again, even if I check the RememberMe `checkbox`.  I was told in a previous post that WebSecurity "handles' all of that for me automatically, but it isn't working. Can it be that I need to add additional code somewhere? Or is my authentication statement in the web.config file missing something?

I've also tried in a different test application version where I added specific cookie language:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
int timeout = model.RememberMe ? 525600 : 30; // Timeout in minutes, 525600 = 365 days.
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(model.UserName, model.RememberMe, timeout);
string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
cookie.Expires = System.DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(52000); //  timeout 
cookie.HttpOnly = true; // cookie not available in javascript. 
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

But this doesn't appear to work, and when I look at the cookie values, it says to expire when Session Ends.

Help! This has been driving me crazy.

---

**UPDATE:**
Been doing a bit of testing as this still doesn't work.

First of all, *I commented out ALL of the code above*, and the *cookies are still happening*. I'm pretty sure this is coming from the `websecurity.Login` process which is passed the username, password and persistCookie: `model.RememberMe`. So I'm getting two cookies ASPXAUTH and RequestVerificationToken that are saved. The ASPXAUTH expires 1 year from the date if I check the Rememberme `checkbox`; otherwise it says to expire when browsing session ends.

However, when I come back to the site after 40 minutes, I've been logged out. When I click Log In, I have to log in manually. This may sound like a stupid question, but do I need to add code to the Login Controller to check for the cookie and auto-log the person? There doesn't appear to be code of that kind by default. And again, I don't understand why Microsoft would provide the RememberMe option in the Views but not provide the code to make it work.

Comment: Start with commenting out the very first line in your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The very first line of your snippet is the possible culprit. It issues the forms cookie with no sliding expiration as you do not have it in your web config.

Then, you issue the cookie manually which gives two forms cookies going to the client side. And unfortunately, the first one causes a user to be signed out.

Comment out the first line, the remaining code seems ok.

Comment: Thanks. I commented that out, but when I do this in Chrome and then look at the cookie data, it is still saying that the cookie (_requestVerificationToken)  expires when the browsing session ends.

Comment: Is this _requestVerificationToken the name of your cookie? Also, did you try to sniff the communication over http with a http debugger and see the cookie value sent from the server? Try Fiddler for example.

Comment: Been doing a bit of testing as this still doesn't work.  First of all, I commented out ALL of the code above, and the cookies are still happening.  I'm pretty sure this is coming from the websecurity.Login process which is passeed the username, password and persistCookie: model.RememberMe.